# Making an if statement in antlr4 not working

Tags: python, antlr4

I've been trying to create an if statement in my programming language in antlr4

My grammar that is failing is:

```
if_stmt: IF conditional_block stmt_block (ELSE IF conditional_block stmt_block)* (ELSE conditional_block stmt_block)?;
```

But it gives the error:

```
line 3:2 extraneous input 'else' expecting {<EOF>, '!', BOOLEAN, 'null', 'func', 'if', 'while', 'for', ID, INTEGER, FLOAT, STRING}
line 4:27 extraneous input ')' expecting {<EOF>, '!', BOOLEAN, 'null', 'func', 'if', 'while', 'for', ID, INTEGER, FLOAT, STRING}
```

It expects 'else'
my code that goes into the program is:

```
if false {
    println("Hello World!")
} else {
    println("This is true")
}
```

Comment: You should post your complete grammar and lexer rules here. Otherwise it is more guessing than helping :(

Answer (score 0):

This look suspicious:

```
(ELSE conditional_block stmt_block)?
```

which should probably be:

```
(ELSE stmt_block)?
```

Not sure if that would solve your problem. If not, you'll need to edit your question and add enough of your grammar so that other are able to reproduce the error you mention.

Comment: That suprisingly fixed it! Thanks!